# Media Library doesn't allow uploads? Upload Directory

Tags: database, media-library, uploads

I just put up a WP 4.31 site.  Most of the content was copied from a different WP site via FTP.  All the stuff in wp-content:  uploads, plugins,themes, etc.

It all seemed to work as usual, and I've done this before with no issue, but now I get this error when trying to upload new content via Media Library:

`Unable to create directory uploads/2015/09. Is its parent directory writable by the server?`

The same exact message occurs when trying to upload plugins, right down to the path...

There already IS a directory `uploads/2015/09`, and it's 755 and seems to be owned by the root user like all other folders.

**UPDATE:**
I am pretty sure it's a DB issue.  I believe it is due to the `wp_upload_dir` field  in the `wp-options` table.  Is this new?  Because it was set to the path from the old server.  I tried setting it to what I *thought* was the path: `/wp-content` but apparently WP was trying to create a whole new tree from that point.

What's the correct setting to use?  I deleted the new install completely and had the hosting CP install a new one.  I checked the default setting for `wp_upload_dir` and it was *blank*.

So I am attempting a new install with that.

Comment: Uploads directory permission in case of shared hosting differ. Please try 750 as instructed on [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Shared_Hosting_with_suexec). If that does not work, then I suggest it will be better if you get in touch with hosting support team which can assist you faster.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `wp-admin/options.php`. There find uploard URL path. Correct it for new username of new server like `home/ankit12/wp` to `home/texh12/wp`.

This will surely fix this.

Comment: Please do not try to spam. Do not use the answer section to advertise/give away personal contact details